# Anchor link not directing to controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, anchor

I have an anchor `<a>` element within a cell of a `<table>`, leading to an action within my app. When I click the link in the browser, the event app goes to the route that I expect it to (`Admin/ManageCustomers/ViewPayments/1`), but the action doesn't get called (I've put a breakpoint on the expected method, but it doesn't get hit). I've double- and triple-checked the names of the controller and action, and compared it to other places in my app where `<a>` elements inside of `<table>`s that *do* work, and I can't figure out why this one is behaving differently.

If it matters at all, both the view and the controller are inside the "Admin" Area, but I think that would still work (I know that the `asp-area` tag for the anchor probably isn't necessary, since both the view and the model are in the same Area, but I was just trying everything I could think of at that point).

Controller:

```
namespace Shop.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
  [Authorize(Roles =Constants.ROLE_ADMIN)]
  [Area(Constants.ROLE_ADMIN)]
  public class ManageCustomers : Controller
  {
   
    ...
    // other stuff
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ViewPayments(int id) // This is the method I want to call
    {
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

View:

```
...
@* stuff *@
...

<div class="container-fluid">
  <main>
      <table class="table table-bordered table">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Balance</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (Customer customer in Model)
        {          
          ...            
          @* stuff *@
          ...
          <tr>
            <td>
              @* This is the element that isn't working right *@
              <a asp-area="Admin" 
                  asp-controller="ManageCustomers" 
                  asp-action="ViewPayments" 
                  asp-route-id="@customer.CustomerId"  @*From the model*@
                  class="text-center">
                View Payment History
              </a>
            </td>
            ...
            @* stuff *@
            ...
          </tr>
        }
      </table>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like a GET request, not POST.  The Controller method you're showing us is the POST method.  Do you have a GET method?

Comment: @devlincarnate Duh, making that change fixed it. Of course someone else could fix a problem literally in minutes that I've spend hours trying to figure out. Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor and url it leads to are `GET` requests.  The method you're showing us in your Controller is expecting `POST`.  You need to either change the method to accept `GET` or create a `GET` method.